# how to copy one workbook sheet to another workbook sheet using apache POI and java

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have one excel file with single sheet (abstract model). Now I want to copy the sheet to another existing workbook. How can I do this?

Comment: A little bit of googling helps: http://www.coderanch.com/t/420958/open-source/Copying-sheet-excel-file-another ..

Comment: The solution proposed in the thread is to use a utility class from jxls (http://jxls.sourceforge.net/, LPGL), and vote for this feature to be included in POI (where it is on the TODO list, http://poi.apache.org/todo.html )

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/848212/copying-excel-worksheets-in-poi the jxls Util class does not work for copying between files.

Comment: It fails when Columns are grouped. It has to be fixed in the code given in the link.http://www.coderanch.com/t/420958/open-source/Copying-sheet-excel-file-excel